# Espresso testing on Webview within ViewPager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, android-espresso

I have an Android Application that uses ViewPager and each Fragment in the view pager has its own WebView. I am able to write test case to check navigation on the ViewPager. But how can I test whether the div in the webview which is first child of the view pager asserts the provided string?

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "desgination")).
                check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("Doctor")));
```

This one throws

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'WebView
>   with JS enabled' matches multiple views in the hierarchy. Problem
>   views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to

```
onWebView(Matchers.allOf(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "desgination"))
    .check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("Doctor")));
```

The isDisplayed() method is needed to automatic select the one that is currently on your screen.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had several fragments with nested WebViews. I was using add/show/hide with the fragmentManager. This meant that `isDisplayed()` returned multiple matches. In the end I assigned a unique contentDescription to each webview:

```
webView.setContentDescription("webView[0]");
```

and located the specific webView with Espresso with:

```
onWebView(withContentDescription("webView[0]"))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "submit"))
    .perform(webClick());
```

Edit: After reading a bit more about the contentDescription it became clear that this is a misuse of the member variable which is intended for accessibility. [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)